# (C programming) while loop only works in a specific order

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

I'm writing a silly code as a joke, sort of a number guessing thing. I thought it was fine until I realized the correct things would only print if I put in the numbers in a specific order. I'm a bit of a beginner, so I'm not sure why it's only printing correctly if I type in the numbers in an order. Is this a condition of while loops in general? Is there a way I can fix this so that it doesn't matter what order the numbers go in? Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int number;

int main()
{
    printf("Enter a number!\n");
    scanf("%d", &number);

    while ((number != 69) && (number != 420))
    {
        printf("hmmm, not the number i was looking for... Enter another number!\n");
        scanf("%d", &number);

        while (number == 666)
        {
            printf("what are you, emo? try again!\n");
            scanf("%d", &number);
        while (number == 420)
        {
            printf("lol close, try the other Funny Number\n");
            scanf("%d", &number);

        while ((number != 69) && (number != 420))
        {
            printf("hmmm, not the number i was looking for... Enter another number!\n");
            scanf("%d", &number);
        }
            while (number == 69)
            {
                printf("haha nice\n");
                return 0;
    }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: "number guessing thing" doesn't tell us precisely what the program is supposed to do. Details matter in programming. We need exact descriptions. Please provide exact input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: Looks like you are using `while` in many places where you should be using `if`. The best advice to you is to run your program in a debugger and step thru it to better understand what the code is doing. And format your code better with consistent indentation - that is actually very important not just for code readability but to be able to check the structure of your logic is correct or not.

Comment: If you apply consistent indentation to your program you will likely get a completely new insight into its inner working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you may be running into is you enter a number and then it gets stuck in an "inner" loop scanning and checking and failing an inner condition instead of all of them.

I'm not sure if you have yet to discover if/else if/else but this is normally how you might check conditional statements.  I will write this in pseudo code to give you a chance to write it yourself in C.

```
number = 0
print "Enter a number"
while number != 69
    number = get number
    if number == 666
        print "What are you..."
    else if number == 420
        print "lol close..."
    else if number == 69
        print "haha nice..."
    else
        print "hmmm..."
```

For extra fun check out switch statements.

Comment: Thank you @foreverska, I fixed it!